# Можно ли как-то стандартными средствами java 1.8 создать на основе старой коллекции новую коллекцию, но с другим типом элементов не через цикл?

Tags: java

Можно ли стандартными средствами java 1.8 создать на основе старой коллекции новую коллекцию элементов, но с другим типом элементов не через цикл?

Например на C# будет выглядеть так:

```
List<Type2> newList = oldList.Select(x => SomeConvert(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Практически так же

```
List<новый тип> newList = oldList.stream()
                                 .map(функция преобразования)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ответ Сергея примером

```
List<String> oldList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
List<Integer> newList = oldList.stream()
        .map(Integer::parseInt)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```